# Impact of multilingual URLs on SEO

Tags: url, seo, multilingual

Do I need to use multilanguage in my URLs? For example:

```
http://mygermanwebsite.example/product/foo
http://mygermanwebsite.example/produkte/
```

Does that have any effect on Google searches? For example I'm searching for "produkte", will both versions have the same ranks on Google searches?

Comment: Why did you guys marked it as off-topic? It's related with programming. I'm designing my URLs so I need to know if I should support it or not.

Comment: What? How is this not related to programming guys? If I asked you whether to use REST or GUIDs in a URL that would be programming related right?

Comment: one thing for sure is that they will rank different

Answer (score 1):

It will improve your google rankings a lot. Use URL rewrite technology to make this possible without lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the URIs doesn't really have an effect for the ranking. You could use http://mygermanwebsite.com/9772 instead and it wouldn't matter.